# Save snippet button sometimes throws an error

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, editor

The ***Save & insert into post*** button in Stack Snippets sometimes throws an error and the popup doesn't close.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

When I refresh the page and try it again, it works fine. This is not a recent issue. It happens couple of times a day.

Console:

[image]

Prettified source code which throws the error:

[image]

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @Cerbrus I forgot to take a screenshot of that. I think it was *"Cannot read save of undefined"* error.

Comment: let's hope it will get fixed one day. I face this at least 40% on all my snippet edits

Comment: @TemaniAfif same. It's very annoying.